# Grep word in one file, and use that word to match in another file, adding the thing that follows the match

Tags: regex, grep, awk

I want to grep several words in file1, and use each word to grep what follows after its match in file2. And then I want to add the string that followed the match to the word I used into file03, so that file03 contains

```
word1 [the thing that was found using word1 in a grep in file2]
word2 [the thing that was found using word1 in a grep in file2]
```

Part of files I have are:
file1:

```
JAN1319964: PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400068385_PGSC0003DMT400096710  PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400062633_PGSC0003DMT400090958 PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400066271_PGSC0003DMT400094596 PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400064671_PGSC0003DMT400092996 PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400068967_PGSC0003DMT400097292
JAN1327159: PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400016823_PGSC0003DMT400024599 PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400017933_PGSC0003DMT400026257 Dul|Dul_comp58749_c0_seq2-1
JAN1330513: Des|Des_g36886.t1 PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400049952_PGSC0003DMT400073802
```

File2:

```
>Dul|Dul_g997.t1
ESECRVQYFSDDEVSPVTEVTGRRGSICVVCRLVPKASVSESSFLK
>Dul|Dul_g998.t1
MDDKRLWEEEERRRIAVRQREERGKIYERQKALEEQEKLAAIESYQDAIRREREEEERLKEKKKKKKKTEIRDDYLDDFLPRRNDRRIPDRDRSVKRRQTFESGRHAKEHAPPTKRRRGGEVGLSNILEEIVDTLKNNVNVSYLFLKPVTRKEAPDYHKYVKRPMDLSTIKERARKLEYKNRGQFRHDVAQITINAHLYNDGRNPGIPPLADQLLEICDYLLEENESILAEAESAI
>Dul|Dul_g999.t1
MDDKRLWEEEERRRIAVRQREERGKIYERQKALEEQEKLAAIESYQDAIRREREEEERLKEKKKKKKKTEIRDDYLDDFLPRRNDRRIPDRDRSVKRRQTFESGRHAKEHAPPTKRRRGGEVGLSNILEEIVDTLKNNVNVSYLFLKPVTRKEAPDYHKYVKRPMDLSTIKERARKLEYKNRGQFRHDVAQITINAHLYNDGRNPGIPPLADQLLEICDYLLEENESILAEAESGIEQ
>Des|Des_g1.t1
FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
```

The output I want is for this example:

```
JAN1319964: PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400068385_PGSC0003DMT400096710 [the line after the match to this name]: FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400062633_PGSC0003DMT400090958 [the line after the match to this name]: FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400066271_PGSC0003DMT400094596 [the line after the match to this name]: FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400064671_PGSC0003DMT400092996 [the line after the match to this name]: FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400068967_PGSC0003DMT400097292  [the line after the match to this name]: FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
JAN1327159: PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400016823_PGSC0003DMT400024599 [the line after the match to this name]: FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400017933_PGSC0003DMT400026257 [the line after the match to this name]: FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
Dul|Dul_comp58749_c0_seq2-1
JAN1330513: Des|Des_g36886.t1  [the line after the match to this name]: FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400049952_PGSC0003DMT400073802 [the line after the match to this name]: FRKQTVELSESDDTSISVETEDAEIENGNSPPAGLSNTTKVQLKPLYRSTIQLTPHPDGLSNTNEIK
```

As you can see, I simply have some information missing in file1, which is contained
in file2, and needs to be added to file1. If anyone knows how to do this I would
greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I don't understand, the first line of your `file1` has no identifiers that are present in the FASTA file2, what do you want to grep for? Are you trying to convert FASTA to [tbl](http://bmerc-www.bu.edu/needle-doc/new/seq-formats.html#tbl-file-format)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, so I'll answer what I *think* you're asking. If you have a file of identifiers of interest like this (I assume the first field is never an identifier, I also assume that at least some of the IDs are present in the sequence file, none of the ones of your example are):

```
Jan12345: ID1 ID2 ... IDN1
Jan67899: ID11 ID12 ... IDN2
```

And a Fasta file like this:

```
>ID1
ABCDEFG
>ID2
HIJKLMN
>IDN1
OPQRSTU
>ID11
WXYZABC
>ID12
DEFGHIJ
>IDN2
KLMNOPQ
```

And you want an output file like this:

```
Jan12345 ID1 ABCDEFG ID2 HIJKLMN ... IDN OPQRSTU
```

You could do something like this:

1. Save this script as `FastaToTbl` and make it executable (`chmod 744 FastaToTbl`):

   ```
   #! /bin/sh
   gawk '{
           if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
          if (NR>1)
                printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
         else 
            printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
          else 
             printf "%s", $0
   }END{printf "\n"}'  "$@"
   ```

   This will convert FASTA to [tbl](http://bmerc-www.bu.edu/needle-doc/new/seq-formats.html#tbl-file-format), (`ID<TAB>SEQUENCE`).
2. Use `FastaToTbl` combined with this script to extract the IDs from `file1` and the sequences from `file2`:

   ```
   FastaToTbl file2 | 
     perl -ne 'chomp;@a=split(/\t/); $k{$a[0]}=$a[1]; ## Collect the sequences
                                                      ## $k{ID}=SEQUENCE
         END{open(A,"file1");   ## Open ID file
            while(<A>){         ## and process it line by line
              @a=split(/\s+/);  ## Gather the IDs in array @a
              print shift(@a);  ## Print the first element (Jan123:)
              print " $_ $k{$_}" for @a; ## Print each ID and its seq
              print "\n";
    }}' 
   Jan12345:ID1 ABCDEFG ID2 HIJKLMN IDN1 OPQRSTU
   Jan67899:ID11 WXYZABC ID12 DEFGHIJ IDN2 KLMNOPQ
   ```

Comment: I tried this (for quite some time), although for some reason the first (FastaToTbl) script did not separate the "Jan..." from the rest with a \t (tab), but with a normal space.

Comment: Also, I am not completely sure, but after adding a tab, I am still not getting the sequences into my output (the last 5 lines looks like this:

    PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400017933_PGSC0003DMT400026257
    Dul|Dul_comp58749_c0_seq2-1
    JAN1330513:Des|Des_g36886.t1
    PGSC|PGSC0003DMP400049952_PGSC0003DMT400073802
    SWtf|SW_g16502.t1

Comment: @Stenemo the FastaToTbl should be run on the FASTA file. In my example, `file2` is the fasta file and `file1` is the one with the ids.

Comment: Ok, it works now, thank you so much for your help!